# Problem with content page in a different folder than master page

Tags: asp.net

I have put the master page in the main directory and content page in a different folder in the same directory. When I try to debug the page, it does not show me any error but the images on the master page are not visible. The content page works fine if it is in the directory itself without any folders. Can anyone let me know if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing images in the master page using relative paths, relative to the location of the master page.
Since the actual page is in a different folder, those relative paths are incorrect.

Instead, you should use absolute paths, or call the `ResolveUrl` function to generate absolute paths from application-relative paths.